# Create UIPopoverController from existing controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, uipopovercontroller

I want to use a UIPopoverController in my application and was trying [this example.](http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=487) The problem is that the view and the controller in that example are created from code.

```
   UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]
                  init];
   UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]
                  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];
   popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   popoverContent.view = popoverView;
```

I want to use an existing controller with it's xib file for the popup. How do I link the popup to an existing controller? And do I need to create the controller's view in some special way for it to match the dimension of the popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an existing xib, just initialize your viewController using the `nitWithNibName:bundle:` method.  When you init using the xib your viewController's view hierarchy will be instantiated for you.

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourXibName" bundle:nil];
```

Don't worry about sizing the view when you initialize - the view gets resized in the example code you cite anyway on the next line when the property `contentSizeForViewInPopover` is set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

```
    MyUIViewController* content = [[MyUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle: nil];
    // additional initialization in loadView

    UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                     initWithContentViewController:content];
```